# PHP template not working, I made a php template engine but I can't merge the output with implode

Tags: php

I coded a template for my framework. I dont know how to merge the two files to the output. I tried using implode to merge the foreach output; I expected a string but I got an int.

My code:

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class render {
    function set($title, $inputParam) {
        $wrapper = file_get_contents("temp/top.php");
        $input = file_get_contents("temp/bottom.php");
        $wrapper = str_replace("{{title}}", $title, $wrapper);
        $inputArr = array();
        foreach($inputParam as $inputHTML) {
            $inputCode = str_replace("{{value}}", $inputHTML, $input);
            echo $inputCode;
        }
    } 
}
?>
top
<?php
$div = new render();
echo $div->set("a title", array("input number 1", "hello world"));
?>
bottom
<?php
$div = new render();
echo $div->set("a title", array("input number 1", "hello world"));
?>
```

top.php is this:

```
<h1>{{title}}<div>{{content}}</div></h1>
```

bottom.php

```
<input name="" value="{{value}}"/>
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what you expect as result, and what is the exact error or the exact problem.

Comment: no errors, it just that i want to make a templater system class. and so heres how the ussage would be. 
first make the objct u want lets a say form
now to fill the form with inputs
so in that object we give parameters like this
array("input value goeshere", "this is another input")
and checkboxes too and etc
noe the final real version would be like this
array("checkbox%%check box txt")
the %% will be exploded to seperate the two vals

Comment: "but i got got expected string got int"   sounds like something does not work as expected.

Comment: I might be missing something in my understanding but if you are using include() nothing will be output so capturing the output buffer won't get you the content of the 2 files you are trying to read. You might try `$c= file_get_contents('temp/bottom.php');` to get that into a string, or `$c = file('temp/bottom.php');` to get into an array?

Comment: oh, i forgot to say that. also, ik how to make a basic templater that has vars but the html stays the same, all i can do is change text or smt, i want to make one that can have a dynamic number of emement and php will make them so if i want 3 inputs i just need to specify that

Comment: i used output buffer then relised i wont have any executablephp code, both do the same thign tho

Comment: @raz I didn't know that use of the ob :-)

Comment: alrgith, i just redid it and fixed some stuff, now my problem is that i am using echo and u cant use multiple returns how can iget arround this

Comment: Add each instance of $inputCode to an array and return that?

Comment: i did actualy,i fixed it a few days ago, ill close this question